# Have custom TinyMCE display on certain pages

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

Hey so I made a custom toolbar row on my tinymce editor in wordpress. But I only want it to display on certain pages. I assume I'd just have to put my code into a conditional tag. Yet it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
if(is_page_template('single-work.php') && is_admin()) {
        //my code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`is_page_template` works only on the front end. For back end go with `global $pagenow`. You can also try with [get_current_screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen).

Comment: hmmm `global $pagenow; if ($pagenow != 'single-work.php') { //code }` has no effect. Is that how you mean? Sorry I'm still a novice with PHP.